# ' set JsonRequestBehavior ' in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I Creating a News Site With ASP.Net MVC5 . Every News has a Like And DisLike .

i Using Ajax and Json for Ban Refresh The Page .

But When i Clicked in Like Or DisLike Show Me This Error :

```
 This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be 

disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow

 GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
```

HomeController :

```
public ActionResult NewsLike(int ID)
        {
           int Like=RNews.Like(ID);
           return Json(Like);
            }
```

Rep_New :

```
  public int Like(int ID)
    {
        var qLike = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                     where a.ID.Equals(ID)
                     select a).SingleOrDefault();
        try
        {
            qLike.Like++;
            db.Tbl_News.Attach(qLike);
            db.Entry(qLike).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                return qLike.Like;
            }
            else
            {
                return qLike.Like--;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return qLike.Like;
        }
    }
```

News.cshtml :

```
<table style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <tr style="color:green;font-size:12px;margin-top:10px;">
                        <td>Like :</td>
                        <td><span id="Like@(Counter)">@item.Dislike</span></td>
                        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("+", "CommentLike", new { ID = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST",UpdateTargetId="Like"+Counter})</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="color:red;font-size:12px;margin-top:10px;">
                        <td>DisLike :</td>
                        <td><span id="DisLike@(Counter)">@item.Dislike</span></td>
                        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("+", "CommentDisLike", new { ID = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "DisLike" + Counter })</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public JsonResult NewsLike(int ID)
{
    int Like=RNews.Like(ID);
    return Json(Like, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

you have to provide JsonRequestBehavior to return Json result to view.

**Note:** Json request Get behavior and HTTP Get request are not same.

Comment: When i Used This Update . Open New Tab then Show The Like

Answer (score 1):

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Update, try this**

```
public ActionResult NewsLike(int ID)
{
   int Like=RNews.Like(ID);
    return Json(Like, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I Need Just The Post Method Not Get

Comment: When i Used This Update . Open New Tab then Show The Like

Comment: @Kianoush Any problem? You mark this as answer but does your problem solved?

Comment: i Put This Question For Solved The Post Problem Not Get